# How to get the list of Cloud Storage Artifacts not currently in use by Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have 5Go of bytes stored in my Cloud Storage from the artifacts built when deploying Cloud Functions.

I have only 10 running functions, so i would like to delete the old artifacts that are no longer in use.

On the Cloud Storage artifact bucket, i do a list of files looking like :

```
gs://eu.artifacts.project-id.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:ffbfd775c315a0208013acefa53fc3a43249217c3e936cce24f30992548d919a
```

I am using the `gcloud` command to list my functions hoping to find some metadata that i could link to these files but i have found none..

For security reason i won't print the output of `gcloud functions list --format=json` but the only three things i have found that i was hoping to be useful are :

```
"buildId": "95a905d5-4012-4750-abf9-d0f24e22f642",
"buildName": "projects/816598790172/locations/europe-west1/builds/9aa915d5-4092-4750-abf9-d1f24e12f642",
"dockerRegistry": "CONTAINER_REGISTRY",
```

But these metadata are not enough to tell among the hundreds of `sha256` which are the ones i can delete safely.

It's probably not something hard but i am unable to find the information on how to get the artifacts currently in use by my Cloud Functions, can you please tell me how ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there is a direct means to provide you the information you seek.

One thing I thought of was to add a lifecycle rule to the storage bucket that deletes objects with create dates older than the earliest deployed Cloud Function.

That will not get ride of all unused images, but it might remove some.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that could indeed do the trick but i would like to accept an official way of understanding how this is linked

Comment: I completely agree there should be a more straight forward way of knowing what is no longer in us.

Comment: I have reached out firebase support to help me out on this, they advised so far to delete directly from the Container Registry but i am not this will do the whole trick, i am waiting for their confirmation

Answer (score 0):

I had recently came across this problem while deploying cloud functions with different triggers and different locations, then I had to look for each bucket and delete them. one way is identify them using the region, all the artifacts created by gcf will have common format i.e.

```
gcf-{v1 or v2}-sources-{projectnumber}-{region}
```

so if you can filter the regions your cloud function are in, then you can delete the others and also all the cloud function will be stored under same bucket that are of same generation and same region.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed i do see this bucket and the function versioning inside but my question is about artifact. the bucket name i should delete things from is : {region}.artifacts.{project_id}.i-appspot.com and in this bucket i can't find a way to link with the existing functions

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question as i have not found any way to actually get a `List` of Cloud Functions but i have ended up deleting all the container registry which is deprecated and the bucket associated.

I have migrated my functions to use Artifact registry which doesn't store anything in Cloud Storage so everything is fine now.